# Можно ли искать фотографии в FaceBook по хэштегам?

Tags: facebook-api

Собственно вопрос. Изучал их API, насколько я понял такой возможности нет.
Может кто-то сталкивался с подобного рода задачами?

Answer (score 1):

После введения `Graph API 2.0` (30 апр 2015) `API Public Feed` недоступен и альтернативы нет. Больше нельзя искать по хэштегу.

`Media Solution Partners` обеспечивают аналогичную (оплачиваемую) функциональность
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mediasolutions/partners

Comment: т.е. оплачиваешь доступ и через них можно будет искать?